# TypeError creating new instance of automapped model from table named items

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a database with a table named "items":

```py
import sqlite3

stmt = """CREATE TABLE items (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)"""
conn = sqlite3.connect('test20210101.db')
conn.execute(stmt)
```

I use SQLAlchemy's [automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html) feature to map the table to a model class:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test20210101.db')
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Item = Base.classes.items
```

However if I try to create a new item, I get a `TypeError`:

```py
>>> new_item = Item(name='foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: items() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Likewise attempts to query the database using the automapped model fail:

```py
>>> items = session.query(Item).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   <lots of traceback>
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got ('items', <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.items'>).
```

Similar code works for other tables, what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the raising of `TypeError` suggests, the problem is that `Item` is not an automapped model as we would expect.  In fact it's a method object:

```py
>>> type(Item)
<class 'method'>
>>> Item
<bound method Properties.items of <sqlalchemy.util._collections.Properties object at 0x7fb088f48fa0>>
```

The problem is that `Base.classes` exposes a dictionary-like API, and `Base.classes.items` is the API's `items` method rather than the automapped object*.

There are at least two ways to work around this name collision:

- access the automapped object using `__getitem__`

  ```py
  >>> Item = Base.classes['items']
  >>> Item
  <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.items'>
  ```
- define a [custom function to map table names to class names](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.classname_for_table) when preparing the `Base`

  ```
  >>> def map_names(base, tablename, table):
  ...     return 'my_items' if tablename == 'items' else tablename
  ...    
  >>> Base = automap_base()
  >>> Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True, classname_for_table=map_names)
  >>> Item = Base.classes.my_items
  >>> Item
  <class 'sqlalchemy.ext.automap.my_items'>
  ```

---

* So the same problem occurs for other dict-related names, for example `keys`, `values` etc.

Answer (score -2):

You are importing the file not the class `Item`

change:

```py
import Item
```

to

```py
from Item import Item
```

Comment: I'm not importing `Item` at all, as you can see in the code in the  question.

Comment: Well, how is the class declared then?

Comment: `automap` automatically generates model classes mapped to tables in an existing database.    There is no explicit declaration or importing involved, beyond that in the self-contained example code in the question.